# How to use if and declare variable in echo statement php

Tags: php

I have a condition within echo statement like this, how to adjust it to make it working:

```
echo "<option value="http://localhost/myproject/index.php?if(empty($_GET['view'])){echo "view=main-content";}else{$view=basename($_GET['view']);echo "view=".$view;}"></option>";
```

Many thanks

Comment: write conditionals outside of echo. make two different echos.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are using two times `view`, threfore if you condition enters the `else` your final url would be something like: `?view=whateverview=whatever2` which is clearly wrong.

```
$view = (empty($_GET['view']) ? 'main-content' : basename($_GET['view']));

echo "<option value='http://localhost/myproject/index.php?view=" . $view . "'></option>";
```

If you would like to add more parameters to the URL you'll need to use `&`.

Answer (score 0):

is this your expected output?

```
$d =  "<option value='http://localhost/myproject/index.php?";
if(empty($_GET['view']))
{
$d .= "view=main-content";
}
else
{
$view=basename($_GET['view']);
$d .="view=".$view;
};
$d .="'>Testing</option>";
echo "<select>". $d."</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it to a variable, and concatenate it with the rest of your echo statement.

```
if(empty($_GET['view'])){ 
    $res = 'main-content';
} else {
    $res = basename($_GET['view']);
}

echo '<option value="http://localhost/myproject/index.php?view=' . $res . '"></option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

And since no one else posted it:

```
echo '<option value="http://localhost/myproject/index.php?view='
   . (empty($_GET['view']) ? 'main-content' : basename($_GET['view'])
   . '"></option>';
```